# How to split string by "#" and store result in a DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, split

I have this string:

```
1#3.doc#0.036/n
2#1.doc#0.026/n
```

I want to split it on `#` and put every line in a single row inside DataTable
like this:

```
1    3.doc  0.036
2    1.doc  0.026
```

I have a DataTable like this:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("FileName", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Content", typeof(string));
```

How can I do that?

Comment: "split string c#" on google has "About 1,940,000 results".. what have you tried? what have you researched?

Comment: @Sayse And this is the first hit!

Comment: @knockando - It isn't for me, it would be a sad day if that is true

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how you would split a string into lines, and then those lines into different parts.

Your string is first split by the new line character `\n` into an array of lines `string[]`.

Then those lines, one by one, are split into parts by `Split('#')`.

And finally those parts are added to your table with the columns you created.

Remember to save the columns you created and don't forget to add the newly created row to the table.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
DataColumn colID = table.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
DataColumn colFileName = table.Columns.Add("FileName", typeof(string));
DataColumn colContent = table.Columns.Add("Content", typeof(string));

string source = "1#3.doc#0.036\n2#1.doc#0.026\n";

string[] lines = source.Split('\n');

foreach(var line in lines)
{
    string[] split = line.Split('#');

    DataRow row = table.NewRow();

    row.SetField(colID, int.Parse(split[0]));
    row.SetField(colFileName, split[1]);
    row.SetField(colContent, split[2]);

    table.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Adding data to the row with `row["FileName"] = data` is also possible, but this will break if you change the name of your column, while references to the column objects are checked by the compiler and your IDE. Also [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30490/How-to-Manually-Create-a-Typed-DataTable) explains how to create a **typed DataTable**, which is something you may want to do.

Comment: I wanted to do something like this: (e.g.) `row.SetField(colContent, split[0] + " " + split[1]` but that didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

erm,

```
var stuff = someString.Split('\n')
    .Select(r => r.Split('#')
    .Select(a => new
        {
            Id = int.Parse(a[0]),
            FileName = a[1],
            Content = a[2]
        })
    .ToList();
```

This will give you an `IList` of an anonymous type. Its not worth putting it in a `DataTable`.

Comment: The question was specifically for `DataTable`. How is "it's not worth putting it in a DataTable" an answer?

Comment: @data because I think the OP's code would be improved by not using `DataTable`. I can't think of a compelling reason to use one.